# What is the difference between “[I] may [be] ...” and “even though ... ”?

Tags: differences, nuance

The above is a question that has occurred to be fairly recently. I admit that there are plenty of cases where they are not even close to equivalent, but how about the following?

> I `may` be visually challenged, but I can see you’re lying.
>
> `Even though` I am visually challenged, I can see you’re lying.

> A stranger I `may` be, but not to places like this, or the kinds of work to be found in them.
>
> `Even though` I am a stranger, not to places like this, or the kinds of work to be found in them.

> Powerful you `may` be and very likely second only to Superman, but Darkseid is a god and he will have your respect…in the moments before he has your soul!
>
> `Even though` you are powerful and very likely second only to Superman, Darkseid is a god and he will have your respect…in the moments before he has your soul!

> The chorus `may` look silly, but they sound wonderful.
>
> `Even though` the chorus looks silly, they sound wonderful.

I should point out that the context surrounding the above sentences suggests that the speaker is admitting a fact and then stating a contrasting fact. They are definitely not expressing permission, possibility or wishes when they say “may” in those cases.

How about you? Do you see any difference between “may” and “even though”. If so, what might that be?

Comment: 'Even though' must be followed by an asserted fact. Your examples 3a and especially 4a allow for the 'It is possible that ...' reading, and this connotation must surely seep through to the 'even though' senses here and quite possibly weaken the 'even though' senses demanded in 1a and 2a.

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: Both versions are concessive, but the "even though" version has more force than the "may" version. The "may" version offers a possibility of the following fact not being the case. The "even though" version admits the fact and leaves no room for a contrary view.

Comment: In this context, *may* normally implies the ***possibility*** of something—it means [**might**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/might); *Even though* implies the absolute existence of something, where something else happens *despite* it. Why do you think they mean the same thing here, and what is the meaning that you are ascribing to both?

Comment: @JasonBassford Please don't write answers in comments; they are harmful to our site. Doing
so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting
community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments, as
well as having [other problems detailed on
meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/3171). Comments 
are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for
other purposes.